# JAXB ignores HashMap properties?

Tags: java, jaxb2

I'm using the JAXB implementation that comes with J2SE to serialize a bean that contains a HashMap property. I would assume that this should work out of the box since 
[this](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_your_favorite_class.html) states

> JAXB spec defines a special handling for Map when it's used as a propety of a bean. For example, the following bean would produce XMLs like the following:
>   ...

This more or less works unless the structure has more than one level, i.e. the HashMap is a property of a bean that is a property of a bean - like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;

class bean { 
    @XmlElement public HashMap<String,String> map;
}

@XmlRootElement class b2 { 
    @XmlElement public bean b;
}


class foo { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        try { 
            bean b = new bean();
            b.map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            b.map.put("a","b");
            b2 two = new b2();
            two.b=b;
            JAXB.marshal(two, System.out);  

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><b2><b><map/></b></b2>` instead of a correctly formatted HashMap. It works if I annotate `bean` with `@XmlRootElement` and remove the `@XmlElement` from `map`, but I don't see why that should be necessary. Is it supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is given on the website you linked:

> Unfortunately, as of 2.1, this processing is only defined for bean
>   properties and not when you marshal HashMap as a top-level object
>   (such as a value in JAXBElement.) In such case, HashMap will be
>   treated as a Java bean, and when you look at HashMap as a bean it
>   defines no getter/setter property pair, so the following code would
>   produce the following XML:
>
> Bean with Map:

```
m = new HashMap();
m.put("abc",1);
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement(new QName("root"),HashMap.class,m),System.out);
```

> XML representation:

```
<root />
```

> This issue has been recorded as #223 and the fix needs to happen in
>   later versions of the JAXB spec.

Comment: The case here is, that the special treatment of a Map as a bean property comes only to effect if the `@XmlElement` annotation is not present. With this annotation the Map is treated itself as a bean. And because there are no JavaBean getters and setters present the resulting XML element is empty.

Comment: ... I had missed that `@XmlElement` causes the field to be treated as a bean. The sample from the question works, now on to the full program...

Comment: themel, if you removed @XmlElemet tag, how did you get it to appear in the xml? It works for me as described, but I have to use getters and setters for bean, otherwise it's not present at all (obviously). However, I don't want to expose getters and setters in my case.